# Why NET Core 3.1 BackgroundWorker in ubuntu can't access environment variables?

Tags: c#, linux, environment-variables, backgroundworker, .net-core-3.0

I have a .net core 3.1 background worker that is installed in ubuntu as a background worker. But It can't get the value of the environment variables which I need for multi-configurations that's why as you can see the value of host environment is the default which is Production.

I already tried getting it thru hostenvironment.environmentname and thru Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable.

My Service file in /etc/systemd/

```
[Unit]
Description=TestService

[Service]
Type=notify
WorkingDirectory=/home/centos/TestService/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/centos/TestService/WorkerService2.dll
User=centos

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Code in NET Core 3.1 background worker.

```
 _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            _logger.LogError("ERROR testing");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Hosting Enviornment: {_hostEnvironment.EnvironmentName}");
            _logger.LogInformation(_configuration["Test"]);
            var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            var contentroothpath = _hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

            Console.WriteLine($"basepath = {basePath}");
            Console.WriteLine($"contentrootpath = {contentroothpath}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"basepath = {basePath}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"contentrootpath = {contentroothpath}");



            var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            var environmentName2 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT");

            _logger.LogInformation($"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = {environmentName}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT = {environmentName2}");
```

Output on cmd.

[image]

[image]

Code in program.cs

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSystemd()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
                //NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration($"{basePath}/NLog.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath}.config");
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile(
                    $"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                //NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration($"/home/centos/TestService/{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.config");
                //NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration($"{basePath}" +
                //    $"/NLog.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.config");
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already got it. I Added Environment=DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Development on .Service file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access HostBuilderContext in Main() to access Hosting Environment something like this

```
 CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.EnvironmentName.ToLower() == "dev")
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.dev.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                else if (env.IsStaging() || env.EnvironmentName.ToLower() == "stage")
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.stage.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);                    

                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            }).Build().Run();
```

Also, don't forget to add environmentVariables

- in launchSettings.json of Project Properties
- On linux, using command `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"` and check environment setting if it's correct using `echo ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

```js
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57993/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @bambamdeo, sorry I edited my post and put the code in program. I already have that configured in program.cs. The problem is the environment is always in Production(default) because my background worker is accessing the environment variables but the value is null or empty.

Comment: That would be because of absence of environment setting in profile of launchSettings.json, I'm adding in the post

Comment: launchsettings.json only works if i run it on visual studio I am not running it on visual studio. I already installed the background worker and set environment variables as well on ubuntu. The screenshots were taken on ubuntu's cmd.

Comment: Oh, Did you try this:
  setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"  , I found out here https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: yeah. ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to staging. Maybe ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is not the key if it is a Background Worker as it is not ASP.NET Core? it is just .NET Core. I already did export DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Development but the value is null.